# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space with tomcat7 windows service

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

i am running **tomcat 7.0.33** on **windows server 2008 R2** 
(i installed tomcat as windows service)

- **JDK version:** `jdk1.6.0_25 64-bit`
- **Tomcat options:**

  1. **Java Virtual Machine:** `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll` 
     (BTW, i don't have client folder inside jre)
  2. **Initial memory pool:** 1000 MB
  3. **Maximum memory pool:** 2000 MB

     when i check the server status, i can see that the server is using 
     the memory i configured.
  4. **Environment Variables (SYSTEM VARIABLES) Configuration:**

     - **JAVA_HOME:** `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25`
     - **Path:** `...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;....`

do i need to add **CATALINA_HOME** and **JAVA_OPTS** system variables too ?

**ISSUE:** i have two web applications **APP1**,**APP2**
when i deploy each one separately, i can find that memory use for

**APP1**= 198 MB
**APP2**= 104 MB

Information about the applications:

**APP1,APP2**: Spring Maven applications that includes in the libraries other small maven spring applications.

APP1: contains webservices, that APP2 uses them.

if i tried to deploy both of them on same tomcat instance, i always get

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

please advise what might be causing this issue.

Comment: is this always after new deployment or after you deployed (e.g. during development) many times?
How many classes are in your webapps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the solution was beside setting initial & maximum memory pool, is to add `-XX:MaxPermSize=1000m` to the java options in the java tab.

Comment: 3000MB?  What, are you developing on a machine with 32GB of memory or something?

Comment: @Makoto, add whatever size you want, i was just missing this param.

Answer (score 9):

You probably need to set/increase the MaxPermSize setting for your Tomcat instance. Note that the MAVEN_OPTS have nothing to do with Tomcat, those are options for the Maven command-line process (mvn). The fact that your application is a "maven" application means nothing at run-time as Maven is not involved in the **running** of your application, only the **building** of it.

In the `\bin` folder in your tomcat installation, there should be an application called "tomcat7.exe". You can use this to update the settings for your tomcat service.

Try something like

> tomcat7.exe //US//[name of your tomcat service] --JvmOptions=-Xmx2g
>   -Xms1g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Edit: above statement should be on one line, not two...

Comment: can you see that i am using 1gb minimum and 2gb maximum from the tomcat manager.

Comment: You still need to add the MaxPermSize directive to the tomcat JVM options.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem as our app run on Tomcat without problems when Tomcat run standalone and we kept getting permgen out of memory exceptions when running Tomcat as a service.

I found a solution simillar to the one of Pap. You need to access the Tomcat service configuration GUI by running bin/tomcat7w.exe //ES//name_of_service. There you go to the Java tab and set respective java properties directly - e.g. 
`-XX:MaxPermSize=1000m`

Here is a blog post which helped me a lot explaining what all Tomcat settings are ignored by Tomcat when running as a service.
http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2010/10/8/Giving-more-memory-to-the-Tomcat-Service-in-Windows

Comment: +1 for that *"Giving more memory to the Tomcat Service in Windows"* link, which explains this so well when Tomcat runs as a **service**.

Answer (score 3):

You need to increase PermGen space. Add something like `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m` to your parameters (you can reserve more perm gen space if you want to). The `-Xmx` and `-Xms` settings are for heap whereas here you're running out of [PermGen space](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2011/07/24/understanding-and-avoiding-the-java-permgen-space-error/) which is administered separately.

Comment: that was my misunderstanding. i must set heap size from tomcat manager and maxpermsize from jvm options in the manager too.